# itextsharp setting background opacity not working

Tags: background, itext, opacity

I have the following code to set background color to one of my fields but for some reason I can not control the transparency of the background. Can someone please take a look at it and let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
 using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Open existing PDF
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

            // PdfStamper, which will create
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);

            var form = stamper.AcroFields;
            var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;


            foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
            {
                if (fieldKey.Equals("Title"))
                {
                    form.SetFieldProperty(fieldKey, "bgcolor", new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(20,225,160,0)),null);
                    form.SetField(fieldKey, "Test");

                }
                else
                {
                    form.SetField(fieldKey, "REPLACED!");
                }
            }
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You're right. That isn't supported and it won't be supported in the future either (what you're trying to do isn't supposed to work). You'll have to use a workaround: get the coordinates of the field and add the transparent background using `PdfContentByte`.

Comment: Even if the source code defines alpha value?
https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/BaseColor.cs

Comment: Transparency in PDF is very different from transparency in other contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the response @BrunoLowagie

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else faces the same problem

```
 var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

            // PdfStamper, which will create
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);
            var form = stamper.AcroFields;
            var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;
            PdfContentByte background;
            foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
            {
                if (fieldKey.Equals("Title"))
                {
                    //form.SetFieldProperty(fieldKey, "bgColor", new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(125,225,160,0)),null);
                    form.SetField(fieldKey, "Test");
                    IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> pos = form.GetFieldPositions(fieldKey);
                    PdfContentByte contentBtye = stamper.GetOverContent(pos[0].page);
                    contentBtye.SetColorFill(new BaseColor(200, 50, 50));
                    contentBtye.Rectangle(pos.FirstOrDefault().position.Left, pos.FirstOrDefault().position.Bottom, pos.FirstOrDefault().position.Width, pos.FirstOrDefault().position.Height);
                    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
                    state.FillOpacity = 0.5f;
                    contentBtye.SetGState(state);
                    contentBtye.Fill();                                   
                }
                else
                {
                    form.SetField(fieldKey, "REPLACED!");
                }
         }
```